# Disambiguation of "identify"

Tags: single-word-requests, disambiguation

I recently heard on the news that:

> Paris police have identified the perpetrators.

I realize this is actually ambiguous (unless I am misunderstanding something).

Have the police...

1)  ...just recently found out the identities themselves?

or

2) ...finally announced the long-known identities to the public?

It is unclear, isn't it?

My question is:

How might this news report have been made more clear without sacrificing conciseness?

**EDIT:**

For those saying that sense #2 is not an option, consider this article [here](https://www.dailysabah.com/europe/2017/06/05/police-identify-perpetrators-of-london-bridge-terror-attack).

Comment: I may be misremembering, but I don't recall seeing _identify_ used in the second meaning you give, at least not in news articles. I would expect “police have released the identities/names of the perpetrators” for that. I would certainly think it unexpected if they wrote “have identified” and it turned out the intended meaning was that they've released already known names.

Comment: "have identified" is the Present Perfect tense. "The present perfect consists of a past participle (the third principal part) with "has" or "have." It designates action which began in the past but which continues into the present or the effect of which still continues."  [owl](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/601/01/)

Comment: Janus - check out this article!  It is used in the 2nd sense:  https://www.dailysabah.com/europe/2017/06/05/police-identify-perpetrators-of-london-bridge-terror-attack

Comment: You are right that it is ambiguous. "Identify" might mean that the police have determined the names of the perpetrators, or it might mean that the police have named the perpetrators (or have released the names of the perpetrators).

Comment: The statement is not ambiguous to me.  The police know the identity of the perps.  No statement was made about the release of those identities to the press or public so you can't (or shouldn't) assume that.

Comment: I think headlines like "[Should underage suspects be identified?](http://www.cbsnews.com/news/should-underage-suspects-be-identified/)" and "[Oakland Police Won’t Identify Suspects Arrested In Gang Sweep](http://sanfrancisco.cbslocal.com/2013/08/23/phil-matier-oakland-police-wont-identify-suspects-arrested-gang-sweep/)" are pretty good examples of your second usage.

Comment: Also, sadly, it's in the best interest of a news outlet to be ambigous these days, as exaggerations and ambiguity are the only weapons they have against people not buying a paper or not reading on. If headlines and articles were clear cut, short and unambigous, most people would probably find them too boring to read. I really think it's sad, as I would much rather read clear and concise news. I hate that news has become (actually been for quite some time) entertainment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I agree it is somewhat ambiguous, I think that, given the context, most people would assume the first meaning -- that the police just figured out whodunnit.

That said, to be completely clear, they could have said either

> Paris police have determined the identities of the perpetrators.

or

> Paris police have released the identities of the perpetrators.

I will also note that the first meaning you identified (ha, see what I did there?) is still ambiguous.  It could mean either that the police just recently found the perpetrators -- "Hey, here's the guy, hiding behind the trash can" -- or figured out the identity of the persons they had already found -- "We've had this guy sitting in the hoosegow for a week now and only just now figured out his name."

Comment: Good point, Roger -- about another level of ambiguity that I missed.  It's even trickier than I thought!

Comment: Good answer.  I would just add that headlines are often like optical illusions.